# How to store this incoming data from back end to an array object of type periodic element

Tags: java, angular, angular8

I am new to angular and I have a requirement where I need to perform some operations to the incoming data and then show it in a table.
my current code fetches data from back end and shows it in a table.
But, what I need is to first store incoming data in a array object and then perform some operations (if else conditions and basic calculations)and then show it in the table.

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
"date":'',
"endDate":'',
"groupa":'',
"hoA":'',
"hoB":'',
"hoC":'',
"mCommission":''
 }

 const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [];

@Component({
 selector: 'kt-dynamic-table',
 templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['dynamic-table.component.scss'],
})
export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit , PipeTransform  {
  tableData : any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['date', 'endDate', 'groupa', 
'hoA','hoB','mCommission','action'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
myTable:any;
inputData:any;
loggedData : any;
index : number;
updateStatus : boolean = false;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
constructor( private apiService:ApiService ,private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Dynamic Table');
    this.inputData = {
        "date":'',
        "endDate":'',
        "groupa":'',
        "hoA":'',
        "hoB":'',
        "hoC":'',
        "mCommission":'',
    };
    this.myTable = [];
    this.loggedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedData"));
    console.log(this.loggedData.id);
    this.getTableData();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}

getTableData(){
    let url = 'http://test1-env.jkbp6sft6f.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/maMaster';
    this.apiService.GET(url).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        this.tableData = resp.body;
        this.updateTable(this.tableData);
        console.log(this.tableData);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }, err => {
    console.log(err);  
    });
}
```

What I am expecting is to get data from back end in array object.
like: 
PeriodicElement[] = incoming data
 then perform operations then show it in a datatable.

Comment: In the subscription itself, you can do the operations you want... what stopped you from doing that?

Comment: @nilesh soni did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your interface properties should have proper typing instead of ''

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
date:string,
endDate:string,
groupa:string,
hoA:string,
hoB:string,
hoC:string,
mCommission:string
}
```

then change your get call to

```
this.apiService.GET(url).subscribe((resp: any) => {
        let data:PeriodicElement[] =resp.body;
        //here perform some opration with data eg. data.map etc.
        this.tableData = data;
        this.updateTable(data);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }, err => {
    console.log(err);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
 date:string,
 endDate:string,
 groupa:string,
 hoA:string,
 hoB:string,
 hoC:string,
 mCommission:string
}
```

And then, in your get you can specify your specific type:

```
this.http.get<PeriodicElement >(url).subscribe(response =>{
    let data:PeriodicElement[] = response ;
});
```

This way you can directly map response without using pipe filters or map operators.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo!!, 
You can use `.map` function provided by `RxJs`

`this.http.get<PeriodicElement >(url).subscribe(response =>{
    let data:PeriodicElement[] = response ;
});`

just write this code like:

```
.map(response =>{ 
 // your working logic should go here now. This the standared way to deal with the 
 responses

 }).subscribe(response =>{
    let data:PeriodicElement[] = response ;
 });
```